# Unable to boot after update

Tags: 12.04, grub2, kernel

After a update, Ubuntu won't boot anymore and gives:

`error: could not read file.`

If I'm fast enough to press a button to continue, I get

`Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

I can however still boot correctly using older kernels.

---

I tried using boot-repair to fix it but that did not help.

boot-repair report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7829705/

- 3.2.0-65 does not work
- tried updating to the latest version (3.2.0-67) but that did not help either.
- 3.2.0-64 still works

Comment: On unknown block? How odd. The 12.04 precise [kernel][1] has a [changelog][2] that shows no recent ext3 changes. Acpi has tripped me up in the past on certain machines with certain disks. One of the items listed just after this line should contain the answer:

    linux (3.2.0-65.98) precise; urgency=low

down to

    Tue, 10 Jun 2014 15:08:47 -0400


  [1]: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/linux
  [2]: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.2.0-67.101/changelog

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/207565/unable-to-boot-error-couldnt-read-file